# Is there a term to describe words with opposites of the same form?

Tags: terminology, antonyms

By "words with opposites of the same form", I mean word pairs such as:

- Input/Output
- Inhale/Exhale
- Import/Export

and so forth.

Is there a term to describe such pairs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the antonyms you intend are indeed linked by form and created by  adding prefixes and/or suffixes to the same root, you could say they are **paronymous antonyms**.

> In grammar and morphology, a **paronym** is a word that is derived
> from the same root as another word, such as *children* and *childish* from
> the root word *child*. Adjective: **paronymous**. Also known as a
> *beside-word*.
>
> In a broader sense, paronyms may refer to **words that are linked by a
> similarity of form**. [Richard Nordquist; "Definition and Examples of
> Paronyms"](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-paronym-1691581)

> **paronymous** (adj.)
>
> Of a word or group of words: derived from the same root; cognate. (OED)

> **paronym** (n.)
>
> A word which is derived from another word, or from a word with the
> same root, and having a related or similar meaning (e.g. *childhood* and
> *childish*); a derivative or cognate word. (OED)